# Theorem on orthogonal automorphism and its homology

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

If $F: \mathbb{R}^{n+1}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ is an orthogonal automorphism then

$$\widetilde{H}(F)=\det F \cdot id : \widetilde{H}(\mathbb{S}^{n})\rightarrow\widetilde{H}(\mathbb{S}^{n}).$$

I've showed that for linear automorphism $f: \mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$ there is 
$$H(f)=sgn\det f\cdot id : H(\mathbb{R}^{n},\mathbb{R}^n\setminus 0)\rightarrow H(\mathbb{R}^{n},\mathbb{R}^n\setminus 0). $$

I got it using some commutative diagram:
$$H(\mathbb{R}^{n+1},\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\setminus 0)\xrightarrow{\partial_* =iso}\widetilde{H}(\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\setminus 0)\xleftarrow{iso} \widetilde{H}(\mathbb{S}^n)$$
$ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \downarrow_{H(s)} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \downarrow_{\widetilde{H}(s)}  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \downarrow_{\widetilde{H}(s)} $
$$H(\mathbb{R}^{n+1},\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\setminus 0)\xrightarrow{\partial_* =iso}\widetilde{H}(\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\setminus 0)\xleftarrow{iso} \widetilde{H}(\mathbb{S}^n)$$

I guess I should put in above diagram $\widetilde{H}(F)$ instead of the right down arrow, but how formally does it work?

Answer (score 2):

There is a simpler solution. Since $f_{|S^n} : S^n \to S^n$ is an homeomorphism, you already know that $f(1) = \pm 1$, so we just need to worry about the sign. If $r$ is a reflexion then $s_*(1) = -1$, but $\deg(r \circ r') = \deg(r) \cdot \deg(r')$ for any map $r,r'$, and also that any orthogonal matrices can be written as composition of rotations and reflexion in an appropriate basis.

Comment: There is some things I haven't met yet. I haven't seen a reflection and I don't understand your solution, Can't we apply (in some easy way) diagram I put?

Comment: My solution looked more natural but I think it is also possible to do with your diagram. Indeed, with your diagram you have $\tilde H(F) = iso \circ H(F) \circ iso^{-1}$, so $\tilde H(f) = \det F = \pm 1$ as $F$ is orthogonal. Where $iso : \tilde H(S^n) \to H(\Bbb R^{n+1}, \Bbb R^{n+1} \backslash \{0 \})$ is the isomorphism of your diagram

Comment: Now I see what's going on here :) I'll study your solution but already I've needed a result using a diagram, thank you :)

Comment: @Yelon : Perfect ! I took a more "geometric solution", but if you have any question please ask ! (Also, you can click on the little green mark if the answer if useful for you, so it is considered as answered).